# Debian Wheezy 7.5 - Variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH not loading in user sessions

Tags: linux, shell, debian, environment-variables, sh

**System: Debian 7.5 Wheezy**

Hi all!!

**Short version**: LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable isn't properly loaded, but the scripts that set it in /etc/profile.d appear to work properly.

**Long version**: Along these days I've been performing an install of Qt5 and several libraries. I've made these installs into the /opt folder. To set environment variables needed after installing, I do this way:

```
gedit setXXXVariables.sh
    #!/bin/sh
    export VARIABLE=value
    export VARIABLE=$VARIABLE:more_values
sudo install -m755 setXXXVariables.sh /etc/profile.d
```

So, I've installed in profile.d several scripts:

```
$ ls -l /etc/profile.d
total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  660 jun 17  2012 bash_completion.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  184 jun  7 14:57 setAndroidNDKVariables.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  203 jun  7 14:52 setAndroidSDKVariables.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  188 jun 15 11:52 setAntVariables.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2444 jun 15 12:05 setIntelIPPVariables.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  508 jun 15 13:15 setOpenCVVariables.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  146 jun  7 15:02 setOracleJDKVariables.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  241 jun 12 02:04 setQt5Variables.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  235 jun 13 17:52 setVTKVariables.sh
```

The content of each file (excluding bash_completion.sh, which came with system and remains untouched) is as follow:

setAndroidNDKVariables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ANDROID_NDK=/opt/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r9d
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_NDK
```

setAndroidSDKVariables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ANDROID_SDK=/opt/AndroidSDK
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools
```

setAntVariables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ANT_HOME=/opt/ApacheAnt/apache-ant-1.9.4
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

setIntelIPPVariables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh 

#RLP 08-06-14: Fichero shell para establecer variables globales de librería Intel IPP (Integrated Performance Primitives) para poder compilar OpenCV con IPP
#/opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64 

#Por alguna razón la línea anterior no fuciona, así que procedemos a establecer las variables manualmente, tras analizar y comparar las generadas por dicho script
MI_VALOR=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/include
if [ -z "${CPATH}" ]
then
   export CPATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export CPATH=$CPATH:$MI_VALOR    
fi

export INTEL_LICENSE_FILE=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/licenses:/opt/intel/licenses:$HOME/intel/licenses
export IPPROOT=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp

MI_VALOR=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/lib/intel64
if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]
then
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MI_VALOR    
fi

MI_VALOR=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/lib/intel64
if [ -z "${LIBRARY_PATH}" ]
then
   export LIBRARY_PATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:$MI_VALOR  
fi

#export MANPATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:
MI_VALOR=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US
if [ -z "${MANPATH}" ]
then
   export MANPATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export MANPATH=$MANPATH:$MI_VALOR    
fi

MI_VALOR=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/mic:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/lib/mic
if [ -z "${MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]
then
   export MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MI_VALOR    
fi

#Look out for NLSPATH var
MI_VALOR="/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64/locale/%l_%t/%N:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/lib/intel64/locale/%l_%t/%N"
if [ -z "${NLSPATH}" ]
then
   export NLSPATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export NLSPATH=$NLSPATH:$MI_VALOR    
fi

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/bin/intel64
```

SetOpenCVVariables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

MI_VALOR=/opt/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9/lib/pkgconfig
if [ -z "$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" ]
then
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:$MI_VALOR
fi

MI_VALOR=/opt/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9/lib
if [ -z "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]
then
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MI_VALOR
else
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MI_VALOR
fi
```

setOracleJDKVariables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/OracleJDK/jdk1.8.0_05
```

setQt5Variables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export QT5=/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$QT5
export QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

SetVTKVariables.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh 
export VTK_DIR=/opt/VTK/VTK-6.1
```

But some vars, in particular LD_LIBRARY_PATH are not properly loaded.

In order to test this, I've created this script in my $HOME folder:

```
echo "CPATH:"; echo $CPATH
echo "INTEL_LICENSE_FILE:"; echo $INTEL_LICENSE_FILE
echo "IPPROOT:"; echo $IPPROOT
echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"; echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo "LIBRARY_PATH:"; echo $LIBRARY_PATH
echo "MANPATH:"; echo $MANPATH
echo "IC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"; echo $MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo "NLSPATH:"; echo $NLSPATH
echo "PATH:"; echo $PATH
echo "PKG_CONFIG_PATH:"; echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
echo "JAVA_HOME:"; echo $JAVA_HOME 
echo "QT5:"; echo $QT5
echo "QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:"; echo $QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE
echo "VTK_DIR:"; echo $VTK_DIR
```

Now, I log in default GUI (Gnome 3), open a Terminal window, and execute this script to see the values:

```
./printMyEnvs.sh
```

**CPATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/include

**INTEL_LICENSE_FILE:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/licenses:/opt/intel/licenses:/home/rlp/intel/licenses

**IPPROOT:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp

**LD_LIBRARY_PATH:**

**LIBRARY_PATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/lib/intel64

**MANPATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US

**IC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/mic:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/lib/mic

**NLSPATH:**

**PATH:**
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r9d:/opt/AndroidSDK/tools:/opt/AndroidSDK/platform-tools:/opt/ApacheAnt/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin

**PKG_CONFIG_PATH:**
/opt/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9/lib/pkgconfig

**JAVA_HOME:**
/opt/OracleJDK/jdk1.8.0_05

**QT5:**
/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin

**QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:**
/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake

**VTK_DIR:**
/opt/VTK/VTK-6.1

Note that NLSPATH and LD_LIBARY_PATH aren't properly set.

Now, if I enter in pure login shell (CRTL+F1 to open pure login shell mode)):

```
./printMyEnvs.sh
```

**CPATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/include

**INTEL_LICENSE_FILE:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/licenses:/opt/intel/licenses:/home/rlp/intel/licenses

**IPPROOT:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp

**LD_LIBRARY_PATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/lib/intel64:/opt/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9/lib

**LIBRARY_PATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/lib/intel64

**MANPATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US

**IC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/mic:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/lib/mic

**NLSPATH:**
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64/locale/%l_%t/%N:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/ipp/lib/intel64/locale/%l_%t/%N

**PATH:**
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r9d:/opt/AndroidSDK/tools:/opt/AndroidSDK/platform-tools:/opt/ApacheAnt/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin

**PKG_CONFIG_PATH:**
/opt/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.9/lib/pkgconfig

**JAVA_HOME:**
/opt/OracleJDK/jdk1.8.0_05

**QT5:**
/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin

**QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:**
/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake

**VTK_DIR:**
/opt/VTK/VTK-6.1

As you can see, now ALL variables have been properly set!! **Why aren't LD_LIBRARY_PATH and NLSPATH set when I open Terminal window in Gnome?**

One could argue that in Debian /etc/profile.d isn't a good place to export variables, but the other ones are OK...

---

EDIT:

If I add lines redefining LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /etc/profile, the result is same as described above (variable OK in shell login, Empty in graphical terminal). This makes sense, because /etc/profile is executed only when a login shell is created. But the other variables are loaded properly in terminal Windows...

Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH managed in some special manner by system?

---

EDIT 2:

If open a Terminal window and force it to enter with a login:

```
sudo login
```

When done, I can see all the vars OK, including LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So, this is a issue concerning the "login-shell" vs "non login-shell"... but this makes no sense, because some vars are loaded and others aren't. Feel puzzled...

Comment: As an aside, these scripts should not need a shebang line; and as you are using Bash syntax, `/bin/sh` is certainly wrong.

Comment: As a matter of fact, these scripts should not use Bash syntax. I.e. every `export var=value` should be converted to `var=value; export var`

Comment: Thanks by your comments! It's always good to improve knowledge with details as the pointed ones by you, guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an acceptable workaround.

I have been struggling with this for 2 entire days... until I posted this this this afternoon, and now tonight I found an explication and workaround. The most useful link I saw was https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728/comments/17

Basically, the ssh init process in X11 resets LD_LIBRARY_PATH and NLSPATH, so programs and terminals launched from window manager (they aren't login-shell) find these variables empty. The solution is to export them before the reset made by X11:

Variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/89preserve_ld_library_path

#RLP 15-06-2014: workaround to get LD_LIBRARY_PATH exported (mainly for OpenCV and Intel IPP libraries, and future others)
STARTUP="/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ${STARTUP}"
```

Variable NLSPATH:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/89preserve_nlspath

#RLP 15-06-2014: workaround to get NLSPATH exported (mainly for Intel IPP library)
STARTUP="/usr/bin/env NLSPATH=${NLSPATH} ${STARTUP}"
```

A point I find really noticeable is the fact that it is a issue/bug noticed since 2009, with no standard solution nowadays.