# Where is LD_LIBRARY_PATH unset

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to something in `/etc/profile`. However when I start a terminal and echo it, it is empty.

[image]
[image]

I added some logs in `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, and restart the system. Here are logs I collected:

[image]

During the process of login, `/etc/profile` is first evaluated, where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set and logged.
Then `~/.profile`, and `~/.profiles` calls `~/.bashrc`. Since it is not an interactive shell, `~/.bashrc` exits earlly.

[image]

When I manually run a terminal and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `~/.bashrc` is evaluated first. But curiously, the value is already empty at the start of `~/.bashrc`.

Can anyone teach me, where was it unset, and who did it?

Comment: _man bash_ is your friend. So, logically, it must happen in a file sourced between /etc/profile and .bashrc. According to the man page, this leaves as candidates ~/.bash_profile and  ~/.bash_login and ~/.profile. If you can't find it from manual inspection of this files, start a new shell with tracing (`bash --login -x`) and inspect its trace.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause and solution here:
[Debian Wheezy 7.5 - Variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH not loading in user sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234212/17580255)

Turns out the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is reset by X11 init.